# Use streaming audiorecord in audiomanager

Tags: android, microphone, android-audiomanager, audiorecord, android-audiorecord

I'm trying to determine the volume level of what is currently being fed through the microphone with 'getStreamVolume' in 'audiomanager'.

THe only available source streams listed in the documentation for audiomanager is for alarms, DTMF, music, notifications, phone ringing, system sounds and phone calls. I'm not sure how to route the microphone through audiomanager in order to get the current volume of the feed.

Any guidance will be most appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`getStreamVolume()` of `AudioManager` returns a volume setting, not the actual volume.

Instead, you need to read the values from the stream, obtain an average over a relatively short space of time, and use that value.

As per the documentation for `AudioRecord`, [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html), Use  `read(byte[], int, int)`, `read(short[], int, int)` or `read(ByteBuffer, int)`.

Comment: Thanks for the response man, though I don't know much about using audio in Java. How am I able to obtain the current volume from reading bytes?